# Vue JS Checkbox select all With Nested Array

Tags: vue.js

I’m not sure If I am doing this correctly but I am trying to collect an Array of Id’s that I will use to update data on my back end,

I implemented checkboxes but I do not know how to add support when parent checkbox is selected to select all children checkbox , and also when select all children checkbox to select parent checkbox ?

here is i'm tried this so far:

```js
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          userlistes: [
            {
              id: 2,
              username: "Larry",
              department_id: 3,
              department: {
                department_name: "IT",
                id: 3,
              },
              worklists: [
                {
                  id: 278,
                  user_id: 2,
                  task_id: 1,
                  date: "2021-07-30",
                  hour: 2,
                  description: "A",
                  is_overtime: false,
                  overtime_hour: 0,
                  task: {
                    taskname: "Task A",
                  },
                  hr_checked: false,
                },
                {
                  id: 277,
                  user_id: 2,
                  task_id: 1,
                  date: "2021-07-30",
                  hour: 3,
                  description: "B",
                  is_overtime: false,
                  overtime_hour: 0,
                  task: {
                    taskname: "Task B",
                  },
                  hr_checked: false,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              username: "Tom",
              department_id: 2,
              department: {
                department_name: "Business",
                id: 2,
              },
              worklists: [
                {
                  id: 259,
                  user_id: 4,
                  task_id: 7,
                  date: "2021-07-27",
                  hour: 6.5,
                  description:
                    "A",
                  is_overtime: false,
                  overtime_hour: 0,
                  task: {
                    taskname: "Task A",
                  },
                  hr_checked: false,
                },
                {
                  id: 260,
                  user_id: 4,
                  task_id: 7,
                  date: "2021-07-27",
                  hour: 0.5,
                  description: "B",
                  is_overtime: false,
                  overtime_hour: 0,
                  task: {
                    taskname: "Task B",
                  },
                  hr_checked: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          isChecklist: [],
          checkAll: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        clickCheckAll() {
          var _this = this;
          _this.checkAll = !_this.checkAll;
          for (var i = 0; i < _this.userlistes.worklists.length; i++) {
            var checkedData = _this.userlistes.worklists[i];
            checkedData.hr_checked = _this.checkAll;
            updateWorkhourAPI(checkedData.id, checkedData);
          }
        },
        clickCheckbox(id, worklist) {
          var _this = this;
          worklist.hr_checked = !worklist.hr_checked;
    
          if (worklist.manager_checked) {
            _this.isChecklist.push(id);
            updateWorkhourAPI(id, worklist);
          } else {
            var last = _this.isChecklist.length - 1;
            _this.isChecklist.splice(last, 1);
            updateWorkhourAPI(id, worklist);
          }
          if (_this.isChecklist.length == _this.userlistes.length) {
            _this.checkAll = true;
          } else {
            _this.checkAll = false;
          }
        },
      },
    };
```

```html
    <b-card no-body class="mb-1" v-for="users in userlistes" :key="users.id">
          <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-0" role="tab">
            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
              <b-button
                block
                variant="outline-primary"
                v-b-toggle="`accordion-${users.id}`"
              >
                {{ users.username }}
              </b-button>
            </div>
          </b-card-header>
          <b-collapse
            :id="`accordion-${users.id}`"
            accordion="table-accordion"
            role="tabpanel"
          >
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="10">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">
                      {{ users.username }} Work-Lists
                    </h3>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Task Name</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Description </th>
                  <th>Hour (hr)</th>
                  <th>Overtime </th>
                  <th>Overtime Hour (hr)</th>
                  <th>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        @click="clickCheckAll()"
                        v-model="checkAll"
                      />
                      <i class="form-icon"></i>
                    </label>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="worklist in users.worklists" :key="worklist.id">
                  <td>{{ worklist.task.taskname }}</td>
                  <td>{{ worklist.date }}</td>
                  <td>{{ worklist.description }}</td>
                  <td>{{ worklist.hour }}</td>
                  <td>{{ worklist.is_overtime ? "Yes" : "No" }}</td>
                  <td>{{ worklist.overtime_hour }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <label class="form-checkbox">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        @click="clickCheckbox(worklist.id, worklist)"
                        v-model="worklist.hr_checked"
                      />
                      <i class="form-icon">
                        {{ worklist.hr_checked }}
                      </i>
                    </label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </b-collapse>
        </b-card>
```

Comment: At a first glance, in `clickCheckAll()`, I see you are performing the loop wrong, since you are looping over `worklists` instead of `userlistes`, this is an array of objects so you have to loop over it first, and then loop over `worklists` inside each object.

Comment: hi SergioCerrutti thanks for your reply, i've tried add another loop for loop over worklists, but when i press @click event it checked all worklists, how to checked all by specific user_id, `for (var i = 0; i < _this.userlistes.length; i++) {  var checkedData1 = _this.userlistes[i];  for (var y = 0; y < checkedData1.workhours.length; y++) {  var checkedData = checkedData1.workhours[y];  checkedData.hr_checked = _this.checkAll;  updateWorkhourAPI(checkedData.id, checkedData);  }  } },`

Comment: Ok I'm trying to understand what do you want to do. So, does `clickCheckAll()` has to check all or all inside a specific user?

Comment: hi Sergio Cerrutti , 'clickCheckAll()' has to check  all inside a specific user by user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out how to solve this problem: `count array index` ,
thanks advanced

```
<b-card no-body class="mb-1" v-for="(users, idx) in userlistes" :key="users.id">
      <b-collapse
        :id="`accordion-${users.id}`"
        accordion="table-accordion"`enter code here`
        role="tabpanel"
      >
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <th>
                 <label class="form-checkbox">
                   <input
                     type="checkbox"
                     @click="clickCheckAll(idx)"
                     :value="allChecked(idx)"
                   />
                   <i class="form-icon"></i>
                </label>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
```

> 

```
 export default {
      data() {
        return { //.. };
      },
      methods: {
        allChecked(idx) {
          return this.userlistes[idx].worklists.some((el) => el.hr_checked)
        },
        clickCheckAll(idx) {
          this.checkAll = !this.checkAll;
          const currentUser = this.userlists[idx]
          for (let i = 0; i < currentUser.worklists.length; i++) {
            currentUser.worklists[i].hr_checked = this.checkAll;
          }
        },
      },
    }
```